# Append json into existing json file using Groovy

Tags: json, file, groovy, merge, append

I'm pretty new to Groovy (and json) and being playing around with this code trying to get it to work, almost but not quite getting there and need a little help...

So what I'm trying to do is parse an existing json file and then add/append additional entries as in below example:

Original Json

```
{
  "organisation": "company",
  "modules": [
    {
        "description": "Module 1",
        "type": "Q1",
    },
    {
        "description": "Module 2",
        "type": "Q2",
    },
    {
        "description": "Module 3",
        "type": "Q3",
    }
  ]
}
```

New Json

```
modules {
        description 'Module 4'
        type 'TEST'
}
```

Intended Final Output

```
{
  "organisation": "company",
  "modules": [
    {
        "description": "Module 1",
        "type": "Q1",
    },
    {
        "description": "Module 2",
        "type": "Q2",
    },
    {
        "description": "Module 3",
        "type": "Q3",
    },
    {
        "description": "Module 4",
        "type": "TEST",
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried many variations on the following code snippet but still not quite getting the right format for my intended output

```
def inputFile = file("modules.json")
def outputFile = new File("modules.new.json")
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)

println "This is our original input JsonSlurper: \n"
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson (json))

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def jsonNew = builder {
    modules {
        description 'Module 4'
        type 'TEST'
      }
    }

println "This is our combined output JsonBuilder: \n"
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson ([json, jsonNew]))
```

Which results in the below:

```
[
  {
    "organisation": "company",
    "modules": [
        {
            "description": "Module 1",
            "type": "Q1"
        },
        {
            "description": "Module 2",
            "type": "Q2"
        },
        {
            "description": "Module 3",
            "type": "Q3"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "modules": {
        "description": "Module 4",
        "type": "TEST"
    }
  }
]
```

Any help sorting this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge maps before produce json:

```
json.modules = json.modules << jsonNew.modules
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, thought it would be something simple like merging them.  However its still not quite there, why does it wrap the entire json as though its an array [ ] ?

Answer (score 0):

`[json, jsonNew]` this just creates an array of objects, it's not adding the new object into the json.modules array.